# Flight to Australia with transit in Düsseldorf and Hong Kong but Passport only Valid for one month

Tags: air-travel, transit, airports

I'm an Australian living in Austria.I'm flying home via Düsseldorf and Hong Kong but my Passport is only valid for about a Month. I'm only staying at each Airport for about an hour so i'm wondering if i will have any problems because my passport is only valid for a nother month. Hope someone can help me
Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

**You should be OK.**  As an Australian citizen, you have an unconditional right to enter Australia, and your travel document (passport) will still be valid when you show it to the airline at check-in.

Schengen exit immigration in Düsseldorf will not stop you from leaving, and you will not go through immigration at all in Hong Kong.  (Note: I'm assuming your flights are booked on the same ticket, which I hope is the case if you only have an hour to transfer.)